# docker: command not found in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

### Background

in my gitlab-ci file I am trying to build a docker image, however even though I have `docker:dind` as a service, it is failing.

### `.gitlab-ci`

```
---
stages:
  - build
  - docker

build:
  stage: build
  image: fl4m3ph03n1x/my-app:1.0
  variables:
    MIX_ENV: prod
  script:
    - mix deps.get
    - mix deps.compile
    - mix compile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .hex/
      - _build/
      - deps/
      - mix.lock

build_image:
  stage: docker
  image: fl4m3ph03n1x/my-app:1.0
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} | docker login --password-stdin -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} ${CI_REGISTRY}
    - docker build . -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
```

The problematic stage is `docker`.
As you can see I am trying to:

1. login into docker
2. build an image from gitlab's registry
3. push that image

### Error

However, I am getting the following error:

> $ echo ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} | docker login --password-stdin -u
> ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} ${CI_REGISTRY} /bin/bash: line 110: docker:
> command not found

Which is confusing, because `docker:dind` is supposed to actually prevent this from happening:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#enable-registry-mirror-for-dockerdind-service

### Question

So clearly I am missing something here. What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM elixir:1.10

# Install Hex + Rebar
RUN mix do local.hex --force, local.rebar --force

COPY . /
WORKDIR /

ENV MIX_ENV=prod
RUN mix do deps.get --only $MIX_ENV, deps.compile
RUN mix release

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT=8080
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash

CMD ["_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

Comment: does  fl4m3ph03n1x/my-app:1.0 have docker installed?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Does it need to? How would I go about it?

Comment: have you used FROM:docker in the top of the file? use an image that have docker

Comment: is `image: fl4m3ph03n1x/my-app` what you're attempting to build?  That shuld probably be `image: docker` which would build `my-app` in an image providing docker

Comment: @DanielFarrell I am confused. if I have `image: docker` in stage `build_image`, then my code will not be there, correct?

Comment: @aliFalahati if I use `FROM docker` in my `Dockerfile` then I wont be able to use `FROM elixir`, which I need to build my project. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could someone then help me modify the `Dockerfile` so it has docker inside it? (I think that will fix it, right?). If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix no I mean  using FROM:docker in your gitlab-ci.yml. Your Dockerfile is ok. you should use an image that have docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image` is used to specify the image in which to run the script.  You want to run the script in a `docker` image, to build your image.

> The image keyword is the name of the Docker image the Docker executor runs to perform the CI tasks.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ciyml

After all, isn't your application image `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` in this?  You don't want to build the image in itself.

```
    - docker build . -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
```